# How to get pixel location of object in image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Suppose I have a binary image shown in below. I want to get the location(pixel value in X,Y coordinates) of all rectangular shapes and also circular shapes. How to detect how many rectangular and circular shapes are present there. I want to get the solution in Matlab. The rectangle and circle may be in different size. The small circles are noise here. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: And where are you struggling? What have you already done? Sounds like a nice task for the Hough transform.

Comment: I have searched on google for this solution. But I was unable to find any solution. I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to:

1. find connected components (`bwconncomp`)
2. find some statistic for each connected component (`regionprops`)
3. discard connected components that are too small, defining a threshold on the area
4. find if the connected component is a rectangle or a circle / ellipse. You can use the *circularity*, defined as `4*pi*Area / (Perimeter^2)`. Perfect circles will have value `1`, squares `0.785`, and so on. So you can define a threshold on circularity to determine if a shape is a circle/ellipse or not.

Here the result, with smaller blobs removed, and circles/ellipses and rectangles in different colors:

[image]

Code:

```
% Read image
img = imread('path_to_image');

% Convert to grayscale
img = rgb2gray(img);

% Remove JPEG artifacts
bw = img > 20;

% Prepare output image
output = zeros(size(bw));

% Compute connected components, and their statistics
cc = bwconncomp(bw);
props = regionprops(cc, 'Area', 'Perimeter');

% Will contain x,y coordinates for rectanles and circles
coord_rect = {};
coord_circ = {};

% Define thresholds on size and circularity
th_size = 200;
th_circ = 0.8;

% For each connected component
for i = 1 : cc.NumObjects

    % Is big enough?
    if(props(i).Area < th_size) 
        continue;
    end

    % Rectangle or Circle?
    circularity = 4 * pi * props(i).Area / (props(i).Perimeter ^ 2);
    [y,x] = ind2sub(cc.ImageSize, cc.PixelIdxList{i});

    if(circularity > th_circ)
        % Circle
        output(cc.PixelIdxList{i}) = 1;
        coord_circ{end+1} = [x, y];
    else
        % Rectangle
        output(cc.PixelIdxList{i}) = 2;
        coord_rect{end+1} = [x, y];
    end

end

% Show results
imshow(bw);
figure();
imagesc(output);
```

Comment: to automate this workflow, you could also consider using the regionAnalyzer App: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/calculate-region-properties-using-image-region-analyzer.html : although circularity is something that's not directly returned by regionprops.